# How to replace the setupwizard.apk with my own?

Tags: android-source

I need to replace the setupwizard with my own to implement some custom initiate, but I don't know how, and is there a way to read the source code of setupwizard.apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define the following intent filter to replace setupwizard.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="5">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

To view the setupWizard.apk code use the following steps
Get these tools:

1) [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar), which is made by a Chinese student. It will translate dex files to jar files

2) [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to view the java files in the jar

The source code is quite readable as dex2jar makes some optimizations.

Procedure:
And here's the procedure on how to decompile:

Step 1:
Convert classes.dex in setupwizard.apk to classes-debug_dex2jar.jar

d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar setupwizard.apk
Note: In the Windows machines all the .sh scripts are replaced by .bat scripts

Comment: Are these .adk and .jar filename just (confusing) placeholders?  There is no 'test_apk-debug'  The d2j-dex2jar.sh then doesn't use these file names.  Do you mean to unzip the setupWizard.apk file and use the classes.dex inside it somehow?